# Dynamic Data to Excel from a JSP page residing in multiple tables under multiple div

Tags: java, javascript, html, excel, jsp

I have a JSP Page containing multiple div's and multiple tables in those multiple div's . I am using AJAX call to render data to those tables i.e. data in those tables are rendered dynamically . Now I have to export all that div tables to excel file , but I am unable to do that. My sample code for JSP page that renders data is :

```
<script>
AJAX method to load data 
</script>

    <div class="xyz">
            <div class="abc">
                <div class="UserInfo">
                    </br><h2>User Info</h2></br>    

                    <table class="table-class">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="label" style='width: 25px'>Venue</td>
                                <td class="data"><label id="comptvl_itenary_venue"></label></td>
                            </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

... some more div here with more tables in same format above.
Now what I have to do is that I have to export all those multiple div resided table data to excel file . For that I have used application/vnd.ms-excel as content type but it only generates excel when table data is static and not contain any CSS , otherwise it will copy whole table code in excel report. 
I have tried java script function too from this reference

```
http://jsfiddle.net/AnilAwadh/cCzqn/4/
```

but it also generates excel when my table does not contain any CSS . Please guide me how can I export dynamic data generated in table containing CSS to excel.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

rather than trying to export the data from the HTML, export the data when you load it (from the Ajax call).  If you have an "export to Excel"  button (or whatever) this can reference the pre-saved excel.